# EXCEPTION DETAILS: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process 3188 Exceeded cursor quota 100, will kill it with Rom MIUI

Tags: android, sqlite

I use this code to load thumbnail on Sdcard, something device work good, but with device use rom MIUI then it have problem 
"EXCEPTION DETAILS:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Process 3188 exceeded cursor quota 100, will kill it"

please help me fix it, thank you.

```
public static Bitmap getThumbnailByPath(ContentResolver cr, String path)
        throws Exception {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "=?",
            new String[] { path }, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long id = cursor.getLong(0);
        return getThumbnailById(cr, id);
    } else
        cursor.close();
    return null;
}

public static Bitmap getThumbnailById(ContentResolver cr, long idPhoto)
        throws Exception {
    return MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(cr, idPhoto,
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND, options);
}
```

Comment: I believe its similar to **OutOfMemoryError**. Try to limit the maximum number of rows you retrieve each time.

Answer (score 11):

You must *always* close your cursors.

Use something like this:

```java
Cursor cursor = ...;
try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        return getThumbnailById(cr, cursor.getLong(0));
    else
        return null;
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```